# RejTM is undecidable using recursion theorem

Tags: theory, computation-theory

Basically I'm trying to prove that rejTM is undecidable using recursion. I know that you basically suppose there is a decdier H for the language, you construct a TM M that get's own code, simulates H on own code and do the opposite of what H tells us about our own behavior

I just don't know how to apply that .. Like I just don't understand it.
Plus how would I change RejTM to a different set like allTM or infTM